# Angular 17 httpClient 400 Bad request POST issue

Tags: angular, httpclient, 400-bad-request

After updating Angular from 16 to 17 and doing any POST requests I started getting

`status: 400 title: "Bad Request" traceId: "00-c7ce813f7dd641f599d9d16f6b1b1178-ba2085650adf43ba-01" type: "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1"`

Any thought?

I tried all recommendations from this article [https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-fix-400-bad-request-error#:~:text=Malformed%20request%20syntax%20%E2%80%93%20incorrect%20syntax,can%20prompt%20a%20400%20error](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-fix-400-bad-request-error#:%7E:text=Malformed%20request%20syntax%20%E2%80%93%20incorrect%20syntax,can%20prompt%20a%20400%20error).
But none of them doesn't work.